# Add a class to an element when it's loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a class to only those `<p>` elements that have an `<img>`.
So far this is what I have, it works, but I don't think I'm doing it right.

```
$(".entry-content p img").addClass(function(){
    $(this).parent("p").addClass("no-orphans-ctnr");
});
```

Here's a **[Demo/fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzea/rtbLwuar/1/)**.

As you can see, I used the `.addClass()` method **twice**. I'm not a jQuery/JavaScript developer but that doesn't look right to me.
Please review and help me improve it.

Comment: The question seems to be how you can find a P tag whose ancestor is of class .entry-content and which has an IMG tag as a child.  Or how to redo this without the outer addClass function:  `$(".entry-content p img").parent("p").addClass("no-orphans-ctnr");`  Either would seem to be off-topic for Code Review:  questions about code not yet written.

Comment: @Brythan, that worked :). I must've been too tired to not have figured out how simple it really was. Thanks! Yes, it was more the second. Not sure how they would be off-topic for Code Review if that's exactly what I needed help with: review my code. For code not written yet SO of course. If you type a separate answer, I'll chose it as the selected answer. Thanks again man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select the `p` elements that have an `img` as child element,
you can use the `p:has(> img)` selector, like this:

```
$(".entry-content p:has(> img)").addClass("no-orphans-ctnr");
```